# How to add footer as additional information in table view swift

Tags: ios, swift, header, tableview, footer

I want to create a footer as an additional information. it's something like this :

[image]

I tried to give a footer, but it showed a title and it's bold.
This footer has smaller font size, and the background of the footer is like outside the table.
How do I do that?

Here's some of my codes

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView()
    if section == 1 {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Additional information here"
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        label.textAlignment = .left
        footerView.addSubview(label)
    }
    return footerView
}
```

UPDATE :

[image]

I'm getting the margin at the very left of the screen.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What are you getting right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your code by setting constraints to the `UILabel`:

```
let footerView = UIView()
if section == 1 {
  let label = UILabel()
  label.text = "Additional information here"
  label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
  label.textColor = UIColor.black
  label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
  label.textAlignment = .left
  footerView.addSubview(label)
  label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
  label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
  label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
  label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
return footerView
```

But it's way simpler to use simply a `UILabel`, since `UILabel` is a `UIView` also, you can return it directly.

Comment: Hey man can you check my updated post?
I have tried to use your Anchors, but it gave me the foother at the very left of the screen. I wish I had +20 from the left margin. 
how do I do that? Thankyou in advance

Comment: You can achieve this with: `label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `viewForFooterInSection` for returning a custom `UILabel`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.text = "Your text"
    label.textColor = .gray
    return label
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `heightForFooterInSection` and `viewForFooterInSection`  delegates to add footerview in TableView. You can customize the values for `UILabel`.

Create and return a label and related height only for related section you want to add footer view.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return section == 1 ? 20 : CGFloat.Magnitude.leastNonzeroMagnitude
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section != 1 { return nil }
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.text = "Additional information here"
    // customize font and colors.
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    label.textAlignment = .left
    return label
}
```